# Loading multiple CSV files in Neo4j with each row of each CSV being a node

Tags: csv, neo4j

I need to upload multiple CSV files in Neo4j with each row of each CSV file being a node. How to effectively do this? I cannot concatenate the CSVs since each row is a label and the rows are the same across multiple CSVs.

It looks like the LOAD CSV command either take a single CSV and generates nodes for each row or takes a bunch of CSVs and makes a node for each CSV. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run the LOAD CSV command several times to import each of your CSVs. If you have unique data repeated across several of those CSVs, consider using [MERGE](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/clauses/merge/#merge-merge-with-on-create-and-on-match) with unique properties, and use ON MATCH/CREATE SET to fill out the additional properties as required.

Comment: Yes, I thought about it. How does one automate it using the terminal to load several LOAD CSV commands?

Comment: You can separate each statement with a ;

For example:
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile.csv" AS row
CREATE (:MyNode {myprop:row.prop});
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///myfile2.csv" AS row
CREATE (:MyNode {myprop:row.prop});